# is access to camera disabled by default for some phone model?

Tags: javascript, android-camera

I need access to the video camera from js.
And learnt that for samsung galaxy note 10 and huawei p20 android 9.1 -  don't have access by default. I mean no popup that asks for permission is displayed. It's working for the others. Wondering if

- these models deny permission by default
- maybe it's due to my self signed ssl cert

Comment: I have always been asked to allow access to the camera, all aps do that. I have had Samsung Galaxy S2, S4 and S9 now and that has been consistent across apps. Maybe you accidentally clicked it away subconciously? I have done some Android and iOS App development. You must always ask the user for permission. They will get a popup to answer with yes or no.

Comment: This what I expect, but for some test users it doesn't work - I've no access to those devices, they claim they didn't change anything. The error message is Permission denied so it's different when you deny permission on the popup box

Comment: Well we can only help you with some code. Can you show us the code accessing the camera? Can you show us your manifest? Are you using external software? Or just the [camera component](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) which already exists? Notice the recommended other packages in that info box from that link.

Comment: I'm accessing the camera from js and using dynamosoft library so the code won't help  I guess. What I can see just <video> tag is used and what I learnt though I can take a picture without asking for permission video is denied. Just wondering is it by default cause it means this functionality will be failing like a lot

Comment: Yes, access to a lot is deactivated by default. That is why you have to ask for permission. It is what other apps do when it asks you to permit access to something. The OS is seeing your application wants to access something it is not allowed to so it deactivates it. If the user gave permission it works. You can find how to do that in tutorials all over.